# Apply CSS style when clicked on SVG element

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to set the CSS style for the clicked element. I have tried to put `:active` `:clicked` `:targed` with the class name and none of these worked. `:hover` effect works fine. Thanks for the answers.

HTML:

```
<a (click)="Clicked(14)" class="lankstumas">
    <ellipse
    class="e-image"
       id="path3769-9"
       cx="43.089287"
       cy="103.09822"
       rx="43.845238"
       ry="39.498512"
       style="fill:#ff7f2a;stroke-width:0.26458332" />
    <text
    class="e-text"
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10.58333302px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332"
       x="22.300594"
       y="99.318459"
       id="text3836"><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan3834"
         x="22.300594"
         y="99.318459"
         style="stroke-width:0.26458332">LANKS - </tspan><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         x="22.300594"
         y="112.54762"
         style="stroke-width:0.26458332"
         id="tspan3838">TUMAS</tspan></text>
         </a>
```

CSS:

```
.lankstumas:hover{
        .e-image{
            transition: .2s fill;
            fill: #FF8504!important; 
        }
        .e.text{
            transition: .2s fill;
            fill:#fff!important;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to set the CSS style for the clicked element.

One approach to achieve this effect is to give the element an `HTML5 Custom data-*` attribute like this:

```
data-clicked="false"
```

You can then use javascript, to detect a click on the element and update the attribute.

To detect the click with javascript, use:

```
myElement.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

To modify the attribute use:

```
myElement.dataset.myAttribute = myValue;
```

**Working Example:**

```js
const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

const showClick = (e) => {
  event.target.dataset.clicked = 'true';
}

for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {

  boxes[i].addEventListener('click', showClick, false);


}
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 6px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box::after {
  content: 'Click me!';
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box[data-clicked="true"] {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.box[data-clicked="true"]::after {
  content: 'Clicked!';
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" data-clicked="false"></div>
<div class="box" data-clicked="false"></div>
<div class="box" data-clicked="false"></div>
<div class="box" data-clicked="false"></div>
<div class="box" data-clicked="false"></div>
```

Comment: Well, it didn't work exactly as you have suggested, but the idea is good. I have added `.box` class in the CSS file with the same content as on the hover effect. Also added `[ngClass]="{'box':clicked14}"` to the `<a>` element. I think I could mark this as solved now.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you want to overwrite inline css. In order to change the color you need to delete the inline styles for the `fill`. Next comes an example:

```css
svg{border:solid;width:90vh;}
.e-image{transition: .2s fill;}

.lankstumas:hover .e-image{fill: skyBlue; }
.lankstumas:hover .e-text{fill:#fff;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-5 60 100 90">

<a class="lankstumas">
    <ellipse
    class="e-image"
       id="path3769-9"
       cx="43.089287"
       cy="103.09822"
       rx="43.845238"
       ry="39.498512"
       fill="#ff7f2a"
       
        />
    <text
    class="e-text"
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:10.58333302px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.26458332"
       x="22.300594"
       y="99.318459"
       id="text3836">
      <tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         id="tspan3834"
         x="22.300594"
         y="99.318459"
         style="stroke-width:0.26458332">LANKS - </tspan><tspan
         sodipodi:role="line"
         x="22.300594"
         y="112.54762"
         style="stroke-width:0.26458332"
         id="tspan3838">TUMAS</tspan></text>
         </a>
</svg>
```